# Why does hinted handoff not work sometimes?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I was testing the effect of playing around with some of the parameters relevant to hinted handoff.
I have 3 nodes in the datacenter with replication strategy as SimpleStrategy. I wrote 200k entries(12 MB) in 2 nodes while the 3rd node was down. After the write was successful, I brought up the 3rd node. 
Now I left the system undisturbed for 3 minutes and after 3 minutes I turned off the 2 nodes that had been on since the beginning. Now I queried the 3rd node via cql.

The above procedure was repeated thrice. All the configurations were exactly similar in the 1st and 3rd iteration.
The parameters I played with were hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb and max_hints_delivery_threads.
In the 1st and 3rd iteration, I had set hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 2048, max_hints_delivery_threads: 4 and in the 2nd iteration I had set hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024, max_hints_delivery_threads: 2.
The observations:

1. In the 1st iteration, node 3 contained more than 195k rows.
2. In the 2nd iteration, node 3 contained more than 60k rows.
3. In the 3rd iteration, node 3 contained **0** rows.

I'm not able to understand what makes hinted handoff work in the first 2 cases, but not in the 3rd case despite the fact that during the 1st and 3rd iteration, all the configurations were exactly similar.

System: RHEL
Cassandra Version: 3.0.14

Comment: As far as I know, there's no reason for this. But given that you only saw this event once, I wouldn't go chasing the issue right away. Try to repeat the same experiment (it's a good experiment), and if it happens, a couple more times update the post with your results.

Comment: I've repeated this several times, but I'm still observing random variations in each iteration.

Comment: If you increase the time to, let us say 15 minutes, do you still get variations?

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. But the data to be copied is only 12 MB. Why should it need so much time with 4 threads and throttle =2048 KB?

Comment: I don't know what triggers the hinted handoff process start, but perhaps, taking into account your results, it doesn't start right away when the node that was down is brought back up.